# Console problem in Spyder showing: an error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: spyder

An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 287, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 19, in 
import pdb
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 73, in 
import cmd
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\Anaconda3\lib\cmd.py", line 45, in 
import string, sys
File "C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\string.py", line 1, in 
first_name =input("enter your name ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Please help ...

Comment: Please remove or rename this file `C:\Users\ISHTIYAQUE HUSSAIN\string.py`. That will fix your problem.

Comment: thanks bro for your help !! @CarlosCordoba